# How to convert a portion of image to clickable button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[image]

this is  image. In this i want to convert +sign part, - sign part as  button .And the first part is a text box

[image]

how can i do that?

when + is clicked number need to be increased , - is clicked number need to be decreased .

Comment: Why dont you use `<input type="number" />` ? Its the same as above.

Comment: @Harry : have u tried anything so far apart from drawing image...i mean any code or fiddle for us???

Comment: thanks for supporting me .But i need to do in that way. Do you know how to do that.

Comment: Use html instead of image in this type of file.
This might be the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199423/how-to-set-image-map-in-a-portion-of-the-background-image

Comment: but it is a tpl file in which i need to add <input type="number" />..

Answer (score 1):

You can try map tag for your image

```
<img src="myImage.gif" width="180" height="126" usemap="#mymap">

<map name="mymap">
<area shape="rect" coords="<!-- cordinates-->" href="#" onclick="increase()" >
<area shape="rect" coords="<!-- cordinates-->" href="#" onclick="decrease()" >
</map>
```

You can also define cursor styles for you image portions.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_area.asp

Comment: But how can i implement a text box and 2 button .Really i didn't know how to map ,content in coords etc

Comment: So, in fact why are you using an image? If you really have to do it in any case. Try using some debugger, like firebug, to create areas on your image.